# Take the complement of DF's subset

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe DF` that I take a subset of rows of:

```
A <- dplyr::filter(DF, months %in% c("Jan", "Feb"))
```

, for example.

Then I want to take the complement of the original `DF`, everything in `DF` thats not in `A`.

I tried `DF[-A, ]`, but this throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be:

```
dplyr::setdiff(DF, A)
```

Comment: It might be helpful to specify `dplyr::setdiff(DF, A)`