# Find the complement with the `subset` function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I work with a package that uses the `base::subset` syntax.
Now I want to find not only the subset, but also the complement.

There was already a similar question, but that doesn't rely on `base::subset`: [Take the complement of DF's subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164141/take-the-complement-of-dfs-subset)

It is somehow possible to find the complement with `base::subset`.

```r
## Example data frame
df <- data.frame(
    a1 = 1:5,
    a2 = 2:6,
    b1 = c(NA, 1:4),
    b2 = rep(NA, 5)
)

## Split part 1
split1 <- subset(
    df,
    (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &
    (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3)
)

## Split part 2
split2 <- subset(
    df,
    (!(a1 >= 3) &
     !(a2 >= 3)) |
    (
        (!(b1 >= 2) |
         is.na(b1)) &
        (!(b2 >= 3) |
         is.na(b2))
    )
)
```

But isn't there an easier way? (The complement should be really the complement, including `NA`s.)

Because I have to repeat it quite sometimes, it might be easier to create a function. But I cannot figure out how to pass arguments, such as `a1 >= 3` to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**keep `NA` condition in `split2`**

```
cond <- with(df, (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &  (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3))
#[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

complement_cond <- !cond | is.na(cond)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

split1 <- subset(df, cond)
split2 <- subset(df, complement_cond)
```

**keep `NA` condition in `split1`**

```
cond <- with(df, (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &  (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3))
cond <- cond | is.na(cond)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

complement_cond <- !cond
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

split1 <- subset(df, cond)
split2 <- subset(df, complement_cond)
```

---

#### A variation of [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52117386/4891738)

**keep `NA` condition in `split2`**

```
cond <- with(df, (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &  (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3))
#[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

split1 <- subset(df, cond)
split2 <- subset(df, !(row.names(df) %in% row.names(split1)))
```

**keep `NA` condition in `split1`**

```
cond <- with(df, (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &  (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3))
cond <- cond | is.na(cond)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

split1 <- subset(df, cond)
split2 <- subset(df, !(row.names(df) %in% row.names(split1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

you could add an unique identifier to your `df` and use `subset` based on that:

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

split1 <- subset(
df,
 (a1 >= 3 | a2 >= 3) &
 (b1 >= 2 | b2 >= 3)
 )


split2 <- subset(df, !df$id %in% split1$id)
```

Comment: Nice solution as well. I selected 李哲源 answer as it doesn't modify the data frame. But this one works as expected as well! Thanks!